# Used the Blog tutorial to create custom entry 'clients', I can't track down the issue

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I originally had some basic authentication and form validation, but have taken out both of those for the sake of troubleshooting.  When at /clients/add after filling out and submitting nothing happens.  When doing this for the /posts/add it works correctly.

Controller/ClientsController.php

```
<?php
class ClientsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');


    public function index() {
        $this->set('clients', $this->Client->find('all'));
    }


    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid client'));
        }

        $client = $this->Client->findById($id);
        if (!$client) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid client'));
        }
        $this->set('client', $client);
    }


    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('client')) {
            $this->Client->create();
            if ($this->Client->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your client has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your client.'));
        }
    }


    public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid client'));
        }

        $client = $this->Client->findById($id);
        if (!$client) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid client'));
        }

        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            $this->Client->id = $id;
            if ($this->Client->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your client has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your client.'));
        }

        if (!$this->request->data) {
            $this->request->data = $client;
        }
    }
    public function delete($id) {
        if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }

        if ($this->Client->delete($id)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The client with id: %s has been deleted.', h($id))
            );
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

Model/Client.php

```
<?php
class Client extends AppModel {
}
```

View/Clients/add.ctp

```
<h1>Add Client</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Client');
echo $this->Form->input('contact');
echo $this->Form->input('customer');
echo $this->Form->input('state');
echo $this->Form->input('district');
echo $this->Form->end('Save Client');
?>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpgP4.png) is the screenshot of database structure in case it is a db related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  what is $this->request->is('client') ?
```

please do not just copy and replace , it should be

```
  $this->request->is('post')
```

Comment: I looked through for this specific issue at one point, and found the error in:
      if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
I missed this error however.
Thank you.